# Ошибка 1053: служба не ответила на запрос своевременно

Tags: c#

Устанавливаю службу с помощью SC.exe

код самой службы

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "\t" + "Hi, I'm testconsole");
                File.AppendAllText(@"c:/TestConsole", DateTime.Now + "\t\tHi, I'm testconsole\n\r");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"c:/TestConsole", (DateTime.Now + "\t" + ex.Message + "\n\r"),
                Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
        }        
    }
}
```

Код инсталлятора

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //вначале все копируем на компьютер
            string Windows = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);
            if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                File.WriteAllBytes(Windows + "\\SysWOW64\\AAA.exe", Properties.Resources.ConsoleApplication1);
            else
                File.WriteAllBytes(Windows + "\\System32\\AAA.exe", Properties.Resources.ConsoleApplication1);
            Process prc = new Process();
            prc.StartInfo.FileName = "sc";
            if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            {
                prc.StartInfo.Arguments =
" create \"AAA\" binpath= " + Windows + "\\SysWOW64\\AAA.exe type= own start= auto displayname= \"AAA\" error= ignore";
            }
            else
            {
                prc.StartInfo.Arguments =
" create \"AAA\" binpath= " + Windows + "\\System32\\AAA.exe type= own start= auto displayname= \"AAA\" error= ignore";
            }
            prc.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("log.txt", (DateTime.Now + "\t" + ex.Message + "\n\r"),
                Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
        }            
    }
}
```

При запуске службы примерно через 30 секунд возникает ошибка 1053. Причем сама служба работает эти 30 секунд. Это видно по логам c:/TestConsole. Но после ошибки она падает. 
Как обойти эту ошибку?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте класс специально для службы:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
}
```

И вызов из main:

```
  static void Main()
  {
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    {
    new Service1()
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
  }
```